# Spigot Server "stops responding " when running long MySQL thread

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am running a Spigot Minecraft server, latest build, and I seem to have an issue. When I run a "long" mySQL import loop, the server crashes:

```
[19:41:58 INFO]: ---------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: The server has stopped responding!
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Please report this to http://www.spigotmc.org/
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Be sure to include ALL relevant console errors and Minecraft crash reports
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Spigot version: git-Spigot-b4417b8-3c48711 (MC: 1.11.2)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Server thread dump (Look for plugins here before reporting to Spigot!):
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Server thread
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 16 | Suspended: false | Native: true | State: RUNNABLE
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3005)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3466)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3456)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3897)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.myththewolf.MythBans.lib.player.PlayerCache.insertPlayer(PlayerCache.java:59)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.myththewolf.MythBans.lib.player.Player.processNewUser(Player.java:62)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.myththewolf.MythBans.commands.importJSON.onCommand(importJSON.java:47)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:650)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:636)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.aM(DedicatedServer.java:437)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:400)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:678)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:576)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Entire Thread Dump:
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: process reaper
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 37 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: TIMED_WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: File IO Thread
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 34 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: TIMED_WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.FileIOThread.c(SourceFile:51)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.FileIOThread.run(SourceFile:30)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Abandoned connection cleanup thread
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 30 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: TIMED_WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Netty Server IO #0
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 25 | Suspended: false | Native: true | State: RUNNABLE
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Thread is waiting on monitor(s):
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Spigot Metrics Thread
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 23 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: TIMED_WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Spigot Watchdog Thread
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 22 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: RUNNABLE
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:454)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.spigotmc.WatchdogThread.run(WatchdogThread.java:76)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Server console handler
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 19 | Suspended: false | Native: true | State: RUNNABLE
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Thread is waiting on monitor(s):
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:169)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:261)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:198)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:169)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:137)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:246)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:261)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:198)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:2145)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2349)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer$2.run(DedicatedServer.java:84)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Thread-5
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 20 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mojang.util.QueueLogAppender.getNextLogEvent(QueueLogAppender.java:77)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.util.TerminalConsoleWriterThread.run(TerminalConsoleWriterThread.java:27)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: DestroyJavaVM
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 18 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: RUNNABLE
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Server thread
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 16 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: RUNNABLE
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Thread is waiting on monitor(s):
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       Locked on:com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3005)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3466)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3456)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3897)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.myththewolf.MythBans.lib.player.PlayerCache.insertPlayer(PlayerCache.java:59)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.myththewolf.MythBans.lib.player.Player.processNewUser(Player.java:62)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       com.myththewolf.MythBans.commands.importJSON.onCommand(importJSON.java:47)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:650)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:636)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.aM(DedicatedServer.java:437)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:400)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:678)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:576)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Server Infinisleeper
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 17 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: TIMED_WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer$1.run(DedicatedServer.java:59)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: NonBlockingInputStreamThread
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 14 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.run(NonBlockingInputStream.java:278)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Snooper Timer
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 12 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: TIMED_WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Signal Dispatcher
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 4 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: RUNNABLE
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Finalizer
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 3 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 ERROR]: Current Thread: Reference Handler
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   PID: 2 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: WAITING
[19:41:58 ERROR]:   Stack:
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
[19:41:58 ERROR]:       java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)
[19:41:58 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[19:41:58 INFO]: Startup script './start.sh' does not exist! Stopping server.
```

What was expected, is to read the `banned-players.JSON` file and loop through the bans, then dump them into the database.

**Import JSON.java:**

```
public class importJSON implements CommandExecutor {
    private DatabaseCommands dbc = new DatabaseCommands();
    private com.myththewolf.MythBans.lib.player.Player pp = new Player();
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command arg1, String arg2, String[] args) {

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

         Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("banned-players.json"));

         JSONArray ROOT = (JSONArray) obj;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Iterator<JSONObject> i = ROOT.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            JSONObject object = i.next();
            String UUID2 = object.get("uuid").toString();
            object.get("created").toString();
            String name = object.get("name").toString();
            String source = "CONSOLE";
            String expires = object.get("expires").toString();
            String reason = object.get("reason").toString();
            ArrayList<String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(!Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(UUID.fromString(UUID2)).hasPlayedBefore()){
                if(!checked.contains(UUID2)){
                    pp.processNewUser(UUID2, name);

                }
            }
            if(expires.equals("forever")){
                sender.sendMessage("------------Importing------------");
                sender.sendMessage("UUID: " + UUID2);
                sender.sendMessage("NAME: " + name);
                sender.sendMessage("EXPIRES: " + expires);
                sender.sendMessage("REASON: " + reason);
                sender.sendMessage("---------------------------------");
                dbc.banUser(UUID2, source, reason);
            }else{
                sender.sendMessage("Skipping.");
            }
        }
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           return true;
       }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**ProcessNewUser method**

```
public void processNewUser(String UUID, String name) throws SQLException
    {
        PlayerCache.insertPlayer(UUID, name);
        ps = (PreparedStatement) MythSQLConnect.getConnection()
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MythBans_PlayerStats (`UUID`,`status`,`group`) VALUES (?,?,?);");
        ps.setString(1, UUID);
        ps.setString(2, "OK");
        ps.setString(3, "DEFAULT");
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
```

**PlayerCache::InsertPlayer Method**

```
public void insertPlayer(String UUID, String name) throws SQLException
    {
        ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MythBans_NameCache (`UUID`,`name`) VALUES (?,?);");
        ps.setString(1, UUID);
        ps.setString(2, name);
        ps.executeUpdate();

}
```

This code works on a localhost server, but not on a remote one (e.g minespan).
Am I just putting to much load on the server at one time? Or is there something I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: try using batch processing.  How many users are you processing?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am new to that term. As of now, there is > 400 users

Comment: Try `close`ing your `ps`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Let me try that.

Comment: @ScaryWombat it still crashes with the same error.

Comment: Is it processing any `users` or is it failing on the first?

Comment: It processes about halfway then spigot crashes.

Comment: @ScaryWombat several more tests, it seems to crash right around the halfway mark every time

Comment: I guess you need to investigate whether the data is bad, or just that your connection is open too long

Comment: @ScaryWombat Hm, not bad data since a localhost run works. Ill see if I can just ease up the connection by running chunks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running an SQL query on the main thread of the server, which is exceeding the time for the tick-rate (50ms) and causing the server to manually crash as a result.

Use Bukkit's scheduler to run your tasks off the main thread: http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming . Additionally, you would ideally have the sql server and the game server on the same machine, if not the same local network.

(This link has been, and always will be around).

Comment: Thanks for your time. This has fixed the issue. Silly me!